# What files were sourced, zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I use oh-my-zsh with zpretzo, and I keep forgetting the zsh files it sources that I want to edit.

How can I ask the shell what source files it sourced?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE
```

From the zsh manual ([`zshoptions(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/zshoptions.1.html)):

> **SOURCE_TRACE**
>
>   If  set, zsh will print an informational message
>     announcing the name of each file it loads. 
>     The format of the output is similar to that for the
>   **XTRACE**
>   option,
>     with the message
>   **`<sourcetrace>`**
>   . 
>     A file may be loaded by the shell itself when it starts up and shuts down (
>   **Startup/Shutdown Files**
>   ) or by
>     the use of the ‘
>   **`source`**
>   ’ and ‘
>   **`dot`**
>   ’ builtin commands.